# how to make WinDivert work on Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, wfp

I am using the open source WFP driver WinDivert for a web filter. It works on Windows Vista and Windows 7 but not on Windows 8. The function DivertSend fails with the message: warning: failed to reinject packet (1237). Does anybody out there know if WinDivert can be used with Windows 8? If so, what can I do to fix this issue. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the problem is specific to Windows 8.  Most people that report 1237 problems manage to solve the issue by uninstalling security/antivirus/firewall software that is (apparently) incompatible with the WinDivert driver.  There are a few related questions here on stackoverflow.